# How to add lines after a certain pattern in go file?

Tags: go, automation

There are many go files where I need to add the same set of lines after an error has been found and it is being returned like the example given below. How can I automate this process?

```
if err != nil {
    // add few lines here
    return err
}
```

Comment: You can give [eg](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/eg) a shot ([usage](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/refs/tags/v0.1.10:refactor/eg/eg.go;l=20)).

Comment: Notepad++ ? Search % Replace? Search for if err != nil { and replace by if err != nil { @CRLF ...

Comment: linux? `find . -type f -name "*.go" -exec sed -i "s_// add few lines here_\nsome\ncode_" {} \;`

replaces `// add few lines here` with 
`some code`

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the "few lines" into a defer statement, so that they automatically get executed on return?